# Cant add data to Charfield

Tags: python, django

Strange error. When I am trying to add some data to my charfield it shows me error like this: `invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

Here is my models:

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    follower = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.follower

class Following(models.Model):
    following = models.CharField(max_length=140) 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.following

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField()
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(Follower)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(Following)
```

Views:

```
if request.GET.get('follow'):
        author = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=username)
        b = "AAA"
        author.followers.add(b)
```

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`followers` is not a CharField, it is a ManyToManyField. You can't just add text to it: you need to create an instance of Follower, or get an existing one, and add it.